# ASP.NET Core MVC Usermanager help a newbie

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm looking for some support with regards to an ASP.NET Core App I am building

In my register model I have the following :

```
namespace DealerManager.Web.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    public class RegisterModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<Employee> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<Employee> _userManager;
        private readonly IUserStore<Employee> _userStore;
        private readonly IUserEmailStore<Employee> _emailStore;
        private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;
        private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

        public RegisterModel(
            UserManager<Employee> userManager,
            IUserStore<Employee> userStore,
            SignInManager<Employee> signInManager,
            ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
            IEmailSender emailSender)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _userStore = userStore;
            _emailStore = GetEmailStore();
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
            _emailSender = emailSender;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }
    }
}

    /// <summary>
    ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
    ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
    /// </summary>
    public class InputModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
        public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Line Managers Email Address")]
        public string LineManagerEmail { get; set; }

        public string? JobTitle { get; set; }
        public string? Location { get; set; }
        public string? Franchise { get; set; }
        public string? Department { get; set; }
    }
```

When I create a new user all of these fields map back to the users table and all works well, I am trying to create an appraisal model that creates an appraisal via my appraisals controller using the fields

```
Start Date, First Name, Last name, Job title, Location, 
Franchise, Department, Email, lineManagerEmail
```

Essentially at the touch of a button I want the action to look up my Users table, and create an appraisal for each employee in the users table.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Stack Overflow does not exist to write your code for you.

Comment: By subclassing `User` or creating a foreign key to another table. Which I'm certain you can read about in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Totally there is no special logic in your need. Here is a simplified sample.

1.Create your model, controller, and view.

**Model**

```
public class Appraisal
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Franchise { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string LineManagerEmail { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAppraisals()
{
    var users = await _userManager.Users.ToListAsync();

    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        var appraisal = new Appraisal
        {
            //Replace the code with your custom appraisal rules
            StartDate = user.StartDate,
            FirstName = user.FirstName,
            LastName = user.LastName,
            JobTitle = user.JobTitle,
            Location = user.Location,
            Franchise = user.Franchise,
            Department = user.Department,
            Email = user.Email,
            LineManagerEmail = user.LineManagerEmail
        };

        _context.Appraisal.Add(appraisal);
    }

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

**View**

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Appraisal

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create Appraisal</h1>

<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="CreateAppraisals">
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

2.Update your DbContext

```
public DbSet<WebApplication1.Models.Appraisal> Appraisal { get; set; } = default!;
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you, this really helped nudge me in the right direction. I am a complete novice at this and really appreciate your guidance.